# How make a twisted python client with readline functionality

Tags: python, twisted, readline

I'm trying to write a client for simple TCP server using Python Twisted.  Of course I pretty new to Python and just started looking at Twisted so I could be doing it all wrong.

The server is simple and you're intended to use use nc or telnet.  There is no authentication.  You just connect and get a simple console.  I'd like to write a client that adds some readline functionality (history and emacs like ctrl-a/ctrl-e are what I'm after)

Below is code I've written that works just as good as using netcat from the command line like this `nc localhost 4118`

```
from twisted.internet import reactor, protocol, stdio
from twisted.protocols import basic
from sys import stdout

host='localhost'
port=4118
console_delimiter='\n'

class MyConsoleClient(protocol.Protocol):
    def dataReceived(self, data):
        stdout.write(data)
        stdout.flush()

    def sendData(self,data):
        self.transport.write(data+console_delimiter)

class MyConsoleClientFactory(protocol.ClientFactory):
    def startedConnecting(self,connector):
        print 'Starting connection to console.'

    def buildProtocol(self, addr):
        print 'Connected to console!'
        self.client = MyConsoleClient()
        self.client.name = 'console'
        return self.client

    def clientConnectionFailed(self, connector, reason):
        print 'Connection failed with reason:', reason

class Console(basic.LineReceiver):
    factory = None
    delimiter = console_delimiter

    def __init__(self,factory):
        self.factory = factory

    def lineReceived(self,line):
        if line == 'quit':
            self.quit()
        else:
            self.factory.client.sendData(line)

    def quit(self):
        reactor.stop()

def main():
    factory = MyConsoleClientFactory()
    stdio.StandardIO(Console(factory))
    reactor.connectTCP(host,port,factory)
    reactor.run()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The output:

```
$ python ./console-console-client.py 
Starting connection to console.
Connected to console!
console> version
d305dfcd8fc23dc6674a1d18567a3b4e8383d70e
console> number-events
338
console> quit
```

I've looked at

[Python Twisted integration with Cmd module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8568241/python-twisted-integration-with-cmd-module)

This really didn't work out for me.  The example code works great but when I introduced networking I seemed to have race conditions with stdio.  This older link seems to advocate a similar approach (running readline in a seperate thread) but I didn't get far with it.

I've also looked into twisted conch insults but I haven't had any luck getting anything to work other than the demo examples.

What's the best way to make a terminal based client that would provide readline support?

http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.conch.stdio.html

looks promising but I'm confused how to use it.

http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.conch.recvline.HistoricRecvLine.html

also seems to provide support for handling up and down arrow for instance but I couldn't get switching Console to inherit from HistoricRecVLine instead of LineReceiver to function.

Maybe twisted is the wrong framework to be using or I should be using all conch classes.  I just liked the event driven style of it.  Is there a better/easier approach to having readline or readline like support in a twisted client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I landed up solving this by not using the Twisted framework.  It's a great framework but I think it was the wrong tool for the job.  Instead I used the `telnetlib`, `cmd` and `readline` modules.

My server is asynchronous but that didn't mean my client needed to be so I used `telnetlib` for my communication to the server.  This made it easy to create a `ConsoleClient` class which subclasses `cmd.Cmd` and get history and emacs-like shortcuts.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

import telnetlib
import readline
import os
import sys
import atexit
import cmd
import string

HOST='127.0.0.1'
PORT='4118'

CONSOLE_PROMPT='console> '

class ConsoleClient(cmd.Cmd):
    """Simple Console Client in Python.  This allows for readline functionality."""

    def connect_to_console(self):
        """Can throw an IOError if telnet connection fails."""
        self.console = telnetlib.Telnet(HOST,PORT)
        sys.stdout.write(self.read_from_console())
        sys.stdout.flush()

    def read_from_console(self):
        """Read from console until prompt is found (no more data to read)
        Will throw EOFError if the console is closed.
        """
        read_data = self.console.read_until(CONSOLE_PROMPT)
        return self.strip_console_prompt(read_data)

    def strip_console_prompt(self,data_received):
        """Strip out the console prompt if present"""
        if data_received.startswith(CONSOLE_PROMPT):
            return data_received.partition(CONSOLE_PROMPT)[2]
        else:
            #The banner case when you first connect
            if data_received.endswith(CONSOLE_PROMPT):
                return data_received.partition(CONSOLE_PROMPT)[0]
            else:
                return data_received

    def run_console_command(self,line):
        self.write_to_console(line + '\n')
        data_recved = self.read_from_console()        
        sys.stdout.write(self.strip_console_prompt(data_recved))        
        sys.stdout.flush()

    def write_to_console(self,line):
        """Write data to the console"""
        self.console.write(line)
        sys.stdout.flush()

    def do_EOF(self, line): 
        try:
            self.console.write("quit\n")
            self.console.close()
        except IOError:
            pass
        return True

    def do_help(self,line):
        """The server already has it's own help command.  Use that"""
        self.run_console_command("help\n")

    def do_quit(self, line):        
        return self.do_EOF(line)

    def default(self, line):
        """Allow a command to be sent to the console."""
        self.run_console_command(line)

    def emptyline(self):
        """Don't send anything to console on empty line."""
        pass


def main():
    histfile = os.path.join(os.environ['HOME'], '.consolehistory') 
    try:
        readline.read_history_file(histfile) 
    except IOError:
        pass
    atexit.register(readline.write_history_file, histfile) 

    try:
        console_client = ConsoleClient()
        console_client.prompt = CONSOLE_PROMPT
        console_client.connect_to_console()
        doQuit = False;
        while doQuit != True:
            try:
                console_client.cmdloop()
                doQuit = True;
            except KeyboardInterrupt:
                #Allow for ^C (Ctrl-c)
                sys.stdout.write('\n')
    except IOError as e:
        print "I/O error({0}): {1}".format(e.errno, e.strerror)
    except EOFError:
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

One change I did was remove the prompt returned from the server and use `Cmd.prompt` to display to the user.  I reason was to support Ctrl-c acting more like a shell.