# Using Cmd module inside a Python Twisted thread

Tags: python, multithreading, cmd, twisted

Refering to this so [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8568241/python-twisted-integration-with-cmd-module), i need to run a Cmd console application that will use Python's Twisted framework for network queries, with the following example:

```
from cmd import Cmd
from twisted.internet import reactor

class CommandProcessor(Cmd):
    def do_quit(self, line):
        print 'bye bye !'
        return True

    def do_hello(self, line):
        print 'world'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    reactor.callInThread(CommandProcessor().cmdloop)
    reactor.run()
```

Everything is finely working, but when executing **quit** command, the console hangs till i hit Ctrl+c, and same if i hit Ctrl+c before executing **quit**, the console also hangs till i execute **quit** command.

It seems the reactor is still working when i exit from the **CommandProcessor().cmdloop**, if it's the issue, i need a way to stop the reactor whenever my thread end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call [`reactor.stop`](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.internet.interfaces.IReactorCore.html#stop) to terminate twisted event loop. `CommandProcess.do_quit` is run in a separated thread; `reactor.stop` should be called using [`reactor.callFromThread`](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.internet.interfaces.IReactorThreads.html#callFromThread)

---

Add `reactor.callFromThread(reactor.stop)` in `do_quit` method.

```
def do_quit(self, line):
    print 'bye bye !'
    reactor.stop() # <------
    return True
```

Comment: Even with *reactor.stop()* the problem is still, typing quit will not get you of the console, it will hang till i hit Ctrl+c.

Comment: @FouratZOUARI, It worked for me. (at least in window 7, python 2.7.6  64bit)

Comment: @FouratZOUARI, What happend if you replace `reactor.stop()` with `reactor.callFromThread(reactor.stop)` or `reactor.callLater(0, reactor.stop)` ?

Comment: It is working, using twisted 12.3
**CommandProcessor** methods are already inside a thread since i started with **reactor.callInThread(CommandProcessor().cmdloop)**, so why should i call the stop explicitly from a thread ?

Comment: @FouratZOUARI, reactor does not stop on the thread termination.